# Is Monzo bank statement acceptable for tier 4 visa application

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, applications

Please i would like to know if UKVI (UK Visa and Immigration) accept Monzo Bank statement for tier 4 visa application. I appreciate your response in advance. Thank you

Comment: Monzo is a bank established and regulated in the UK. Why would they not?

Comment: Are you referring to statements downloaded online or those requested via chat https://monzo.com/help/account-and-profile/bank-statement-how-to/

Comment: @Traveller Am referring to the stamped bank statement that can be requested from the monzo chat.

Comment: Monzo has a UK bank licence. They're as much bank as any other bank. Especially, if you get mailed the statements with proper stamping and everything. Not everyone will even accept a downloaded statement from Lloyd's Bank, so this is no different. Just a different process of requesting stamped statements.

Answer (score 2):

The only criteria that the UK government issues to travellers for financial documents is very broad:

> 2. Other documents you may want to provide – all visitors
>
> This section provides guidance on the types of documents that you may want to provide to help us consider your application against the Immigration Rules.
>
> - ...
> - financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available. These must clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as:
>   bank statements

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

The [guidance documents](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf) issued by the UK Home Office for visit visas also does not mention anything specific about financial supporting documents.

Your application will be judged on its merit - UK immigration deals with bank statements and other financial statements from an extremely diverse range of sources and will have means at their disposal to evaluate their accuracy and authenticity as a result.

I see no reason why documents from a specific bank would not be accepted so long as they pass the desired scrutiny.